# Is there a Google Search API console or browser?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-search-api

Is there a Google Search API console or a way to browse the indexes and documents stored in them? I can't seem to find it in the Google Cloud Console or anywhere else.

Comment: Question is bit confusing. What do you want to search exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it under App Engine:

https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/search?project=your_project_id

Comment: Thank you. Should be easier to find!